# MSBuild TypeScript not regenerating all JS files

Tags: typescript, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, jasmine, cakebuild

I've incorporated TypeScript in an existing VS2017 Solution for a few files so far. What I noticed is between developer PCs we are getting failed Jasmine tests sometimes because msbuild is not regenerating all TypeScript files to JS on solution build or msbuild from the command line "build.bat". So stale files are being used sometimes. The generated JS are not being cleaned during build.bat btw.

What is the recommended changes to support up to date generated JS files for our build.bat (CAKE building msbuild solution, Karma JS test run)?

Comment: As you want a total regenerate of all the TypeScript files, you can use solution rebuild or msbuild command like: msbuild xxx.xxproj /t:rebuild . If it works or not, afeedback would be expected.

Comment: Hi, Sean, could you share a simple sample which have same issue by one-drive link, so that I can build and check it directly on my side. And do you mean the build even fail when building in VS IDE? Looking forward to your reply.